# numpy.random.multinomial: Is there a way to do a True or False test?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Using numpy.random.multinomial, I was wondering if it would be possible to go through a column of values in a pandas dataframe and either assign them the status True or False. For example, I have these values in a pandas dataframe.

```
col1 col2
240 0.0193549635804102
449 0.019230695266556665
355 0.01901116107244241
29  0.01886820933146161
301 0.017441394009229984
```

With a 40% chance of True and a 60% chance of False, I'd like to use numpy.random.multinomial to generate a dataframe that should look something like this

```
col1 col2                 T/F
240 0.0193549635804102    True
449 0.019230695266556665  False
355 0.01901116107244241   True
29  0.01886820933146161   True
301 0.017441394009229984  False
```

Looking at the documentation for numpy.random.multinomial, it doesn't look like there's an easy way to do this, and it might be easier to use something else. I'd appreciate some thoughts on how to do this

Comment: Why do you want to use `numpy.random.multinomial` if all you seem to want to have is a True/False with 40/60% probability? `np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.4` would do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to do something like:

```
df['T/F'] = np.random.choice([True, False], p=[0.4, 0.6], size=len(df))
```